# Is there a way around, Visual Studio's Code Analysis UNTRUE Warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-analysis

i am getting this "ill defined for loop" for my c++ code below

```
size_t total = someValue;
if (total > 0)
    for (size_t i = total - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //some loopy work

        if (i == 0)
            break;
    }
```

Warning C6295   Ill-defined for-loop:  'unsigned __int64' values are always of range '0' to '18446744073709551615'.  Loop executes infinitely.

As you can see, i am double checking for the safety of unsigned data types, with "total > 0"  and inside the loop with "i == 0" for breaking the loop so "i--" wouldnt cause "overflow"

I don't want to disable this "C6295" warning from "ProjectOptions->C++->Advanced->Disable Specific Warnings" section, because some day i might make a mistake, (or someone else i work with)

Is there a way around this wrongful warning accusation of Code Analysis?

Comment: `i >= 0` is always true, so it is useless as a stop clause in the for. Just remove it. Or use a while loop.

Comment: Thanks Mat, how the heck i din't realise that all this time :)
i think i refactor my code as "for (size_t i = total - 1; ; i--)" or maybe check for "while" loop or something as you just said

Comment: You can safely have the condition `i > (size_t)-1` in the middle of your `for` Statement: unsigned types (like `size_t`) are guaranteed to wrap around on overflow. Which method you choose to look backwards over an unsigned type is mainly a matter of taste.